# Using Cocoa NSSavePanel in non-Sandboxed causes Assertion failure

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nssavepanel

Only in MacOS 10.15, only when trying to save a file twice to the same directory, and only after opening a NSOpenPanel then tap Cancel or Open. My app hangs up with the following stacktrace and the app does not recover, and I had to kill it.

*** Assertion failure in -[NSSavePanel _attachSandboxExtensions:toURL:orURLs:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-
1894.30.142/Nav.subproj/OpenAndSavePanelRemote/NSVBOpenAndSavePanels.m:711
-[NSSavePanel observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] caught non-fatal
NSInternalInconsistencyException 'unexpected class type for sandbox extension string!' with 
backtrace (

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bc5c8ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff61f16805 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bc85d10 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff2e37e241 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff297987b2 __53-[NSSavePanel _attachSandboxExtensions:toURL:orURLs:]_block_invoke + 240
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bbd4037 __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bbeac36 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 80
7   AppKit                              0x00
```

Does anybody have the same problem and a solution for this?

This is the code I am using to save the file:

```
@IBAction func saveAct(_ sender: Any) {
 let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
 defaultPath = UserDefaultUtil.pathDir

 savePanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: defaultPath)
 savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "export"
 savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["jpeg"]
 savePanel.accessoryView = accessoryView

 // <--------------- Assertion failure HERE (the beginSheetModal not called) 

 savePanel.beginSheetModel(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: {(num) -> Void in

      if num == .OK {
           ....
      }else{
           ....
      }
 })
```

}

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Non-sandboxed app, works on Catalina, except in one case, where it crashes with the same stack trace, on the first try of saving a file.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of fixing this problem:

1. Add file extension to your filename while saving. Modify your code to

   `savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "export.jpeg"`
2. Implement NSSavePanelDelegate by setting `save panel delegate to self` and implement following function:

   `func panel(_ sender: Any, validate url: URL) throws { return TRUE; }`

Comment: In objective C neither of these appear to solve the problem any more.

Comment: @RichardWilliamson Please refer the other answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are assigning directory path in `savePanel.directoryURL`, not the file path.
For example:
`savePanel.directoryURL` should have a value `/Users/macbook/Documents/`
NOT `/Users/macbook/Documents/file.txt`

Comment: This is the correct answer. In fact, the problem is visible in the UI. If we pass the path to the file itself for `directoryURL`, we can see the file pre-selected with a light gray background! The internal inconsistency is between the `nameFieldStringValue` and the name of the pre-selected file.